# Exception Unhandled: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Expected: main Calling: Thread-19'

Tags: xaml, camera, maui

Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Expected: main Calling: Thread-19'

This is my code:
CameraPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace J2MobilePClock
{
    public partial class CameraPage : ContentPage
    {
        private bool isCameraOpen = false;
        public ICommand OpenCameraCommand { get; }

        public CameraPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OpenCameraCommand = new Command(async () => await OpenCamera());
        }

        // Method to store UUID
        protected async Task StoreUuidAsync(string uuid)
        {
            try
            {
                await Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.SetAsync("StoredUuidKey", uuid);

                Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    // Update the label text on the main UI thread
                    uuidLabel.Text = "UUID: " + uuid;
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error storing UUID: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // Method to get stored UUID
        protected async Task GetStoredUuidAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string storedUuid = await Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.GetAsync("StoredUuidKey");

                Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    // Update the label text on the main UI thread
                    uuidLabel.Text = "UUID: " + storedUuid;
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving stored UUID: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        private async void BtnOpenCamera_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await OpenCamera();
        }



        // Open the camera
        private async Task OpenCamera()
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                cameraView.IsVisible = true;
            });

            try
            {
                if (!isCameraOpen)
                {
                    await cameraView.StartCameraAsync();
                    isCameraOpen = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error opening the camera: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void cameraView_CamerasLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if the camera is already open before changing cameras
            if (!isCameraOpen)
            {
                // Set the camera to the first available camera
                if (cameraView.Cameras.Count > 0)
                {
                    cameraView.Camera = cameraView.Cameras.First();

                    // Start the camera if it's intended to be open
                    if (isCameraOpen)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {
                            await cameraView.StartCameraAsync();
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No cameras available.");
                }
            }
        }


        // Event handler for barcode detection
        private async void cameraView_BarcodeDetected(object sender, Camera.MAUI.ZXingHelper.BarcodeEventArgs args)
        {
            string scannedUuid = args.Result[0].Text;
            barcodeResult.Text = $"{args.Result[0]}";

            // Store the scanned UUID persistently
            await StoreUuidAsync(scannedUuid);

            // Hide the camera view after scanning the barcode
            Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                cameraView.IsVisible = false;
            });
        }
    }
}`
```

I am getting this exception and have no clue why i cant find whats wrong.
Supposedly my program scans a qr code and stores the data which is currently a uuid, it was working fine before but i wanted to make it on a different page and ever since it has stopped working.

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: You can try to put the code about `cameraView` into the mainthread.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT by main you mean the mainpage? thats where it was before and it worked perfectly fine so thats why im sort of confused and dont know whats wrong, preferably id like it on a different page but migh have to leace it on the same one for now.

Comment: @Jason thats just it it doesnt say where it just happens ot atleast im not seeing it, this is what it says:

"Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException
  Message=Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Expected: main Calling: Thread-18
"
this is he call stack:   0x11 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw C#

Comment: What I mean is putting it  in the `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger until you hit the exception